# Regex to split up message_txt over 160 characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split message text for a messaging system up into at most 160 character long sequences that end in spaces, unless it is the very last sequence, then it can end in anything as long as it is equal to or less than 160 characters.

this re expression '.{1,160}\s' almost works however it cuts of the last word of a message because generally the last character of a message is not a space.

I also tried '.{1,160}\s|.{1,160}' but this does not work because the final sequence is just the remaining text after the last space. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

EXAMPLE:

```
two_cities = ("It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was " +
         "the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the " +
         "epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the " +
         "season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the " +
         "spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had " +
         "everything before us, we had nothing before us, we were all " +
         "going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct the other " +
         "way-- in short, the period was so far like the present period," +
         " that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being " +
         "received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of " +
         "comparison only.")


chunks = re.findall('.{1,160}\s|.{1,160}', two_cities)
print(chunks)
```

will return

['It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of ',
'incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything before us, we ',
'had nothing before us, we were all going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct the other way-- in short, the period was so far like the present period, ',
'that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison ',
'only.']

where the final element of the list should be

'that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.'

not 'only.'

Comment: Can you add some examples.

Comment: [No regex required.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -  `.{1,160}(?:(?<=[ ])|$)`

```
 .{1,160}                      # 1 - 160 chars
 (?:
      (?<= [ ] )                    # Lookbehind, must end with a space
   |  $                             # or, be at End of String
 )
```

Info -

By default, the engine will try to match 160 characters (greedily).
Then it checks the next part of the expression.

The lookbehind **enforces** the last character matched with `.{1,160}` is a space.
Or, if at the end of the string, no enforcement.

If the lookbehind fails, and not at the end of string, the engine will backtrack to 159 characters,  then check again. This repeats until the assertion passes.

Comment: Ayyy that worked thanks a bunch! Could you maybe explain it a little bit?

Comment: @money_dance - Added more explanation.

Comment: Why do you need a lookbehind? This seems to work fine:
`'.{1,160}(?:\s|$)'`

Comment: @Håken - It could be a format issue. Then why not `.{0,159}(?:\s|.?$)` for a total of 160? It's easier to tack on a requirement with the lookbehind because it doesn't obscure what the main requirement is 1 - 160. There is no degraded performance whatsoever. And the integrity of maximum of 160 can be maintained, even if a change in the lookbehind content is needed.

Comment: @Håken - And tacking on a lookbehind in this way is a good substitute for having to make more complex alternation sub-expressions. Its a nice trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using a regular expression, since they can be inefficient.

I would recommend something like this: ([see it in action here](http://repl.it/7i6/1))

```
list = []
words = two_cities.split(" ")

for i in range(0, len(words)):
    str = []
    while i < len(words) and len(str) + len(words[i]) <= 160:
        str.append(words[i] + " ")
        i += 1
    list.append(''.join(str))

print list
```

This creates a list of all the words, split on spaces.

If the word will fit onto the string, it will add it onto the string. When it cannot, it adds it to the list and starts a new string. At the end, you have a list of the results.

Comment: Or just use `import textwrap; textwrap.wrap(two_cities, 160)` 

But I don't think there's anything wrong with using a regular expression. In many cases it's the simplest and most elegant solution.

Comment: Edited to use a list for `str` since it's faster. Does anyone know if my code above could be rewritten with list comprehensions?